# Exception Thrown Trying to Add Document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Every time I try to add a Document to my Azure DocumentDB I get an AggregateException containing one exception: "Owner resource does not exist". The code I use is below and the DbName and TransCollection values are correct as they work fine when I query the database, as does the DocumentClient object.

```
await Client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/ " + DbName + "/colls/" + TransCollection, record, null, true).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, or at least where to look for more help?

Comment: Whenever I've gotten this error, it's been one of two things:

1. Either I had already deleted the resource that the link was pointing to, or
2. The link itself was composed wrong. I suggest checking the values of DbName and TransCollection to be certain that they are trimmed and that transCollection doesn't end in a "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of composing the Uri yourself manually use these DocumentDB SDK Helpers:

```
UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("myDbName", "myCollectionName");
```

Or, for Documents:

```
UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("myDbName", "myCollectionName", "idOfDocument");
```

As shown [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-adds-upsert/).

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it, but I've no idea why it was only necessary for inserts.

Comment: You can use it on Queries too :) It just avoids any URL malforming.